# React Native cannot access express backend

Tags: react-native, express

I have made a REST API for my react native application and want to fetch data from it, though this is not possible for me.

I have tried using localhost and ipv4 as the url, but it doesn't help at all. I also get an "Network Error" at times when I change to the different URLs, which I don't fully understand why they show up, since ipv4 or localhost should work.

I usually get a warning about the metro server after a while, if that has anything to do with it.

How can I connect my React Native client to my express backend?

Comment: code when u make that calls, also you can call your server through postman ?

Comment: have you changed the domain when you make API call? (localhost => 10.0.2.2)

Comment: Postman works, though when I do it from react native client it does not

Comment: I have as well tried 10.0.2.2, and I have tried the expo url that has shown up when running the client.

Answer (score 1):

try to run this command, it will link the port in you device which you run your React Native app with the port of your laptop,
"adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000"
then run "react-native run-android"
i work with the port 3000, you can work with the port you want

Comment: I use expo, I am not sure if that matters. ADB reverse did not work since i don't have any devices/emulators. I expect port 3000 to work for me as well, though it doesn't. I have used the REST-extension and POSTMAN to test my API, and it does work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue! I forgot a / in my base url, which broke the whole thing with axios. And I had one too many in my login post request!